# Bridge 5Ghz to 2.4ghz in WiFi router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, wireless-bridge

Bridge 5Ghz to 2.4Ghz... Our office building updated their network with APs but they removed 2.4Ghz in the process and some of our devices only have 2.4Ghz.

If I receive the 5Ghz into our WiFi router, can I bridge that to 2.4Ghz? Or would it be received to WiFi router via 5Ghz, out to Switch/Router via Ethernet, into a different WiFi Router to Bridge Ethernet to 2.4Ghz?

I don’t want to bother the landlord to get the third party company to “turn on” the 2.4Ghz, as we are positive they would charge for such a hard thing. (Sarcasm).

Comment: Pretty sure it's not the "Enable 2.4 GHz" checkbox that they charge you for, it's also the planning of non-overlapping channels/frequencies across the entire office, taking into account your neighbours etc.

Comment: i would let landlord claim that under warranty because the company didn't do their job right! nevertheless of course you can always connect your own wifi hardware in client mode and let all 2.4 clients connect, but that would break mac address based security because although all clients may get ip from origin DHCP they all share the same mac address (unless you create non-bridged subnet with it's own DHCP which will isolate 2.4 clients behind NAT and configure MAC filter yourself)

Comment: Routers with a 5GHz radio almost always have a 2.4GHz radio, which needs to be enabled to solve your issue... you cannot bridge WiFi radios, only networks/subnets and ports.

Comment: In fact, you _do_ want to bother the landlord. Don’t go for hacks unless you have exhausted every possibility to have 2.4 GHz re-enabled.

Comment: @user1686 Ok, so 5 minutes to perform a Wifi channel check, which I can perform myself on my Mac using Wifi Diagnostics->Window->Scan and not the $500+ charge that some IT folks would charge for a small commercial office building.

Comment: @DanielB I hear you, and I will be asking the landlord to enable but want to be prepared for either a "No" or "Yes for a Fee" being that my landlord is 70 y/o he's been taken advantage of before.

Comment: i don't understand the problem. you already pay a montly rent, you have all rights to get what you payed for. with the current settings there is simply no service provision pursuant to the provisions of the agreement (no wifi)

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** bridge an access point (AP) on 2.4 GHz to a station (STA) on 5 GHz, because by default your WLAN uses 3-address mode. so your building AP on 5 GHz doesn't work with MACs "behind" your STA MAC.

You **can** bridge LAN to an AP on 2.4 GHz, assuming you can connect your WiFi router somehow with a LAN to the building router (no WLAN in between allowed, it must be a LAN port on the building router/switch).

If bridging doesn't work, you can still route and NAT from the 5 GHz WLAN BSS: Your 2.4 GHz "private" WLAN BSS will have a different subnet, and will look like a single IP address to the building router. Which means you can establish connections **from** your WLAN BSS to the rest of the building, but the rest of the building won't be able establish connections to anything in your WLAN BSS.

It depends on the firmware of your router if you can actually configure it for any of the above scenarios. If you can install an alternative firmware on it, like OpenWRT, you'll definitely will be able to.

Comment: I have a router that I can install OpenWRT and will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

There are three more options:

- use a WiFi Extender that can send out a 2.4 GHz signal as well (not sure if they are still available)
- bridge the 5GHz to LAN and attach a a 2.4GHz AP to the LAN (e.g. via an WiFi extender that has an Ethernet port or simple Windows machine that brides the the WLAN and Ethernet network card).
- if you have access to a Ethernet port or the Ethernet switch itself just connect a regular 2.4GHz AP.

You don't need a router as a separate device unless you want to create a new subnet, use NAT etc.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, will check out these options to see what I can do here and also give @dirkt solution.